# Need guidance for downloading pdf in cypress

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

I am writing a E2e test case in cypress in which I have to download a pdf file and also I have to verify the PDF data.
On Web page I have Download CTA/button (which has the HTML Download).
Can anyone please guide me how I can do this in cypress.
I already tried the **cypress-downloadfile** plugin but it did not work in my case. Also I want that test case implementation should work on CI.
Guidance and suggestion would be really appreciating.
Thanks!
(I am writing test case in JavaScript, following mocha chai)

Comment: So when you click on the Download button, does the file explorer open with Save and cancel buttons?

Comment: Yes, when I click on the download button the file explorer open.